# Auto completion in VSCode disappears when typing

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

In my extension, I want to add autocompletion capability for custom XML entities. The code i'm using is following:

```
let entityCompletionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('xml', {

        provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
            let entities = [
                '&systemd;',
                '&suse;',
                '&productname;'
            ];
            let result = [];
            entities.forEach(entity => {
                let completionItem = new vscode.CompletionItem(entity);
                completionItem.kind = vscode.CompletionItemKind.Keyword;
                completionItem.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString(entity.substring(1,));
                result.push(completionItem);
            });
            return result;
        }
    }, '&');
```

when i type `&` or press `CTRL+SPACE`, it does the following:

[image]

While the built-in system entities (`&amp;` ...`&quot;`) work fine and get filtered when i start typing, my custom ones (`&productname;` ... `&systemd;`) dont have the `&` sign colored and disappear from the list as long as i start to type for example `pro...`

Any idea how to fix this?